# how to send an obect using post to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here i have "bookAppointment" object i am redirecting to another actionresult with this object but the values of this object are displaying in the url like

http://localhost:54592/ServiceConsumer/AppointmentStatusPage?BookingID=401&RefBookingID=BED0414_401&SubLocationID=2&ProviderID=9&ProviderName=kalpana%20challa&ProviderEmail

but i dont want to display values of object i need to display until this http://localhost:54592/ServiceConsumer/AppointmentStatusPage

and this is my code:

```
 return RedirectToActionPermanent("AppointmentStatusPage", "ServiceConsumer", new RouteValueDictionary(bookAppointment));
```

and my actionresult:

```
public ActionResult AppointmentStatusPage(BookAppointment bookAppointment)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserID"].ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookAppointment.TransactionStatus))
                {
                   return View(bookAppointment);
                }
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("guestsearch", "Home");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: use Modal binding and use submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following :

in your first controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           BookAppointment model = new BookAppointment() { TransactionStatus = "Passed" };
        return View(model);
        }
```

your first view :

```
@model BookAppointment


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("AppointmentStatusPage", "ServiceConsumer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="btnGo" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="Go" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TransactionStatus);
}
```

In your second controller :

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AppointmentStatusPage(BookAppointment bookAppointment)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserID"].ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookAppointment.TransactionStatus))
        {
            return View(bookAppointment);
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("guestsearch", "Home");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User decorate the Action result with HttpVerb (i.e POST) as under:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Object obj)
{
  //Your code goes here...
}
```

For complete example visit this page:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx

Hope this helps, mark this as answer if you get the solution right.

Regards,

N Baua

Comment: if i use HttpPost it is giving error like  "The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly".